# How many teams of 5 players can you form with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

A local sports club has 10 players. You need to form a team of 5 players. How many teams can you form that include the best player and exclude the worst player?

Comment: When asking a question, it is best to first search to see if any duplicates exist.  If you had trouble finding a duplicate that exists, that's not horrible... we can flag it if we know it is out there.  It is however expected that you show some effort from your part on attempting to find a solution on your own.  Tell us what you tried, what you understand about the problem, and what difficulties you had in continuing on your own.  It is greatly frowned upon here to just copy-paste a problem statement with zero effort or context.

Comment: I will also point out that even if this problem appeared in a course where probability is eventually taught or tied in, the problem itself is only about counting how many outcomes exist.  Probability is not even mentioned or even relevant in this problem as it is currently written and so should not be included in the title or tags.  Further, the title of a question should have to do with the *specifics* about the question and generally should never include names of fields of mathematics like "combinatorics, probability, algebra" or words like "problem, question, etc..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you must include the best player (assuming she is unique), we need only pick $5$ further people, from the remaining $9$. However, we can't pick the worst player (again, assuming uniqueness), so there are really only $8$. So the question is equivalent to

> How many different ways can we choose $4$ people from a group of $8$?

There are $8$ choice for the first, $7$ for the next, $6$ for the third and $5$ for the last one. So there are $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5$ different ways to choose the team, where the ordering matters.

But note that choosing players with labels $\{3,7,6,2\}$ gives the same team as reordering $\{7,3,6,2\}$. So we must divide by the total number of orderings. How many orderings of $4$ objects are there? Label the first $1$, which is $4$ choices; second $2$, which is $3$ choices; then $2$ choices; then only $1$ choice. This gives $4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$ options.

Hence the final answer is
$$ \frac{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = 70.$$
Check out the [Binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) (Wiki link) to learn more about these!